# How to get all objects and related images in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I've been struggling with this for past 2 days and I really need some new input!

First my configs:

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name           = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    objects        = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Item(models.Model):
    name           = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=200)
    description    = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True)
    date           = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=True)
    category       = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    order          = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    active         = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    objects        = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'items'

class ItemImage(models.Model):
    image          = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    order          = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    main           = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    cover          = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    item           = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='items', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    objects        = models.Manager()


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'item images'
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    all_items = Item.objects.filter(active=True)
    pics = []
    for a in all_items:
        images = ItemImage.objects.filter(main=True)
        pics.append(images)
    propert = Item.objects.filter(active=True)
    context = {
        'pictures': pics
    }

    return render(request, 'gallery/index.html', context)
```

Template:

```
<div id="image-popups" class="grid">
    {% for pic in pictures %}
      <div class="item">
          <img class="lazy" src="{{ pic.image.url }}"
            data-mfp-src="{{ pic.image.url }}" 
            data-effect="mfp-zoom-in">
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

My goal is to get all Items filtering for "active=True" and all of their related images with the value "main=True".
I thought about just querying the ItemImage model with "main=True" filter, but I will need to retrieve the description and name sometime in the future.
Should i use ManyToMany relation here?

I can get this to work if I use .objects.get(pk=..), but this returns only one item.

The end result I'm aiming for:

- image_1 from item1 with active=True
- image_1 from item2 with active=True
- image_2 from item2 with active=True
- image_1 from item3 with active=True
- etc.

Comment: where you use 'a' -  for a in all_items:

Comment: you can apply if condition inside the for loop of HTML page

Comment: sorry, don't fully understand your idea, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simply do that by:

View: send all image items queryset through the context

```
def index(request):
    context = {
        'pictures': ItemImage.objects.filter(main=True).order_by('item')
    }

    return render(request, 'gallery/index.html', context)
```

Template: iterate over image items and show them

```
<div id="image-popups" class="grid">
    {% for pic in pictures %}
      <div class="item">
          <img class="lazy" src="{{ pic.image.url }}"
            data-mfp-src="{{ pic.image.url }}" 
            data-effect="mfp-zoom-in">

         <p>{{ pic.item.name }}</p>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

### Update

queryset for with images from active item:

```
 ItemImage.objects.filter(main=True, item__active=True).order_by('item')
```

If you want to show the images for a single item, then you need to define a view regarding that. You can use [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) here.

Lets say you have built a view which returns an Item(simillar to your current implementation), then you can show the images related to the item in template like this:

```
{% for pic in item.itemimage_set.all %}
     <img class="lazy" src="{{ pic.image.url }}"
            data-mfp-src="{{ pic.image.url }}" 
            data-effect="mfp-zoom-in">

{% endfor %}
```

This is called related objects. Please see the documentation on that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/).

Finally, lets say you have defined your view and your url looks like this:

```
path('item/<pk:int>/', your_view, name="item-details"),  # <-- defining name here is important
```

Then you can provide item details urls in `gallery/index.html` like this:

```
<div id="image-popups" class="grid">
    {% for pic in pictures %}
      <div class="item">
          <img class="lazy" src="{{ pic.image.url }}"
            data-mfp-src="{{ pic.image.url }}" 
            data-effect="mfp-zoom-in">

         <a href={% url 'item-details' pic.item.pk %}>{{ pic.item.name }}</a>  
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

For **named** urls, please see the documentation regarding [url namespace](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces).

Comment: Ok, this kinda works, but how can i filter for "active=True" in item model? The purpose here would be to have the ability to toggle which items and their related images show up in the template. Also i need to order the items using .order_by('order').

Comment: eventually I wish to use the same query when clicking on an item image in order to open a new page where i could view all of the images associated with the specific item object

Comment: OMG it finally clicked for me, Thank you very much!!